# Nginx Ingress Cookie-based routing

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Do you know if it's possible to use Nginx Ingress and route traffic based on a cookie?

Example: Host mydomain.com, if cookie OLD exists it routes to service1, if not service2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the feature you are looking for is called "Sticky Sessions" and yes, it is supported by [Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/).

Comment: No, that's different than sticky session. With sticky you cannot say that if this cookie IS present select this service.